# Перемещение элемента вправо влево курсором мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ряд элементов которые выходят за границы своего родителя , при нажатии на мышь, нужно сделать, чтобы они начали перемещаться вправо/влево, написал такой
код, когда двигаем в одну сторону, то элементы перемещаются туда куда надо, но когда меняем направление то элементы все еще продолжают двигаться в первоначальном направлении, пока курсор мыши не дойдет до положения в котором был зажат.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы как только курсор меняет направление, то и направление движения элементов изменилось.

Понимаю, что нужно отследить больше ли предыдущее `mouse_x(n)` положение текущего `mouse_x(n+1)` или нет, в зависимости от этого выполнить функцию, но не понял как это реализовать

```js
position = false;
var startx = 0;
var starty = 0;
var pos = $('.child').offset().left;
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
i = 0; // ставлю счетчик
function SCREENmove() {
  width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

//буду использовать в будущем чтобы запретить элементу отрываться от края экрана
  widthP = $('.parrent').width();
  widthCh = $('.child').width();
  pos = $('.child').offset().left;
  
}
$(window).resize(SCREENmove);
$(document).ready(SCREENmove);

$('.parrent').mousedown(function(event) {
  position = true;
  startx = event.clientX;
  starty = event.clientY;
  i = 0;
})
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  position = false;

})
document.onmousemove = mousemove;

function mousemove(event) {

  if (position) {

    mouse_x = y = 0;
    if (document.attachEvent != null) {
      mouse_x = window.event.clientX;
      mouse_y = window.event.clientY;
    } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {
      mouse_x = event.clientX;
      mouse_y = event.clientY;
    }
    mx = mouse_x - startx;
    pos = pos + mx / 40;
    i++
    console.log('pos=' + pos + '; mx=' + mx + '; i=' + (i++));
    $('.child').css('transform', 'translateX(' + pos + 'px)');


  }
}
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background: #8BC34A;
  margin: 2px;
}
.parrent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.child {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(-394px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child onselectstart=" return false "">
    <div class="item-1 block" style="width: 100px"></div>
    <div class="item-2 block" style="width: 120px"></div>
    <div class="item-3 block" style="width: 300px"></div>
    <div class="item-4 block" style="width: 70px"></div>
    <div class="item-5 block" style="width: 150px"></div>
    <div class="item-6 block" style="width: 200px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы элемент начал двигатся в другую сторону при изменении направления движения мыши, нужно это изменение отследить. Для этого мы вводим две переменные: direction, собственно направление, и prev_x, предыдущее значение положения мыши. Сравнивая текущее и предыдущее пложение мыши мы можем узнать направление движения (увеличилось- вправо, true, уменьшилось, влево, false). Если текущее направление не равно сохраненному в direction, это начало нового движения элементов, поэтому startx = текущему х.

```js
position = false;
var startx = 0;
var starty = 0;
var prev_x = 0; //предыдущее значение
var direction = true; // направление
var pos = $('.child').offset().left;
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
i = 0; // ставлю счетчик
function SCREENmove() {
  width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

//буду использовать в будущем чтобы запретить элементу отрываться от края экрана
  widthP = $('.parrent').width();
  widthCh = $('.child').width();
  pos = $('.child').offset().left;
  
}
$(window).resize(SCREENmove);
$(document).ready(SCREENmove);

$('.parrent').mousedown(function(event) {
  position = true;
  startx = event.clientX;
  starty = event.clientY;
  i = 0;
})
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  position = false;

})
document.onmousemove = mousemove;

function mousemove(event) {

  if (position) {

    mouse_x = y = 0;
    if (document.attachEvent != null) {
      mouse_x = window.event.clientX;
      mouse_y = window.event.clientY;
    } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {
      mouse_x = event.clientX;
      mouse_y = event.clientY;
    }
    if (direction != (prev_x > mouse_x)) startx = mouse_x; // проверяю, изменилось ли направление, и если да, старт с этого места
    mx = mouse_x - startx;
    pos = pos + mx / 40;
    i++;
    direction = prev_x > mouse_x
    prev_x = mouse_x;
    
    console.log('pos=' + pos + '; mx=' + mx + '; i=' + (i++));
    $('.child').css('transform', 'translateX(' + pos + 'px)');


  }
}
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background: #8BC34A;
  margin: 2px;
}
.parrent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.child {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(-394px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child onselectstart=" return false "">
    <div class="item-1 block" style="width: 100px"></div>
    <div class="item-2 block" style="width: 120px"></div>
    <div class="item-3 block" style="width: 300px"></div>
    <div class="item-4 block" style="width: 70px"></div>
    <div class="item-5 block" style="width: 150px"></div>
    <div class="item-6 block" style="width: 200px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: чем приведенный пример отличается от кода в вопросе?

Comment: При изменении направления движения по х изменяется направление смещения.

Comment: пояснение надо добавить в сам ответ

Comment: Не могли бы вы дать ссылку на правила, которые это требуют?

Comment: [Как написать хороший ответ?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: [Пожалуйста, переносите всё важное из комментариев в вопрос и ответ](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2408/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82)